# Migrating s3 download to CloudFront from iOS / Android app

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have iOS and Android apps that download files for s3. Since we have worldwide customers, so we would like to migrate to CloudFront.

I understand that in order to do that, I need to construct a url from / and send NSURLRequest. This means I am no longer using the dedicated S3GetObjectRequest to get an object from bucket.

I wonder if it's the only way to do it, or there's a way to work with s3 classes with cloudFront?

this is my code (iOS):

```
- (int) request:(NSString*)request response:(NSData**)response
{    
    NSInteger httpStatus = 0;
    NSData* theData = NULL;
    NSString* cloudFrontDomain = [self cloudFrontDomain];
    if(cloudFrontDomain){
        NSString *urlString = [cloudFrontDomain stringByAppendingPathComponent: request];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = nil;
        theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&httpResponse error:&error];
        httpStatus = [httpResponse statusCode];
    }
    else{
        NSString* bucket = [self s3BucketName];
        S3GetObjectRequest* s3Request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey: request withBucket:bucket];
        S3GetObjectResponse* s3Response = [s3Service getObject:s3Request];
        theData = [s3Response body];
        httpStatus = [s3Response httpStatusCode];
        [s3Request release];
    }

    if (httpStatus == 200)  {
        *response = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:theData];
    } 
    return httpStatus;
}
```

Android:

```
byte[] request(String key) {    
    String cloudFrontDomain = getCloudFrontDomain();
    if (cloudFrontDomain != null){
        try {
            String url = cloudFrontDomain + "/" + key;
            URL myFileURL = new URL(url);
            InputStream response = myFileURL.openStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(response, outputStream);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch ... {
            ....
        }
    }
    else{
        String bucket = getS3BucketName();
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key);
        try {
            S3Object response = s3Service.getObject(request);
            if (null != response){ 
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                IOUtils.copy(response.getObjectContent(), outputStream); 
                return outputStream.toByteArray();
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch ... {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to use the proper get object with cloudfront? I dont want to get my objects via normal http because i want my objects private

Comment: Any luck on this question? I'm in the same position as @JoãoNunes (using iOS to access files from a bucket, through cloudFront, without using https, and S3GetObjectRequest from the iOS SDK)

Comment: The problem here is not the https but if you want to keep your files private or public. In private (it uses https for authentication) and thus cloudfront won't work (it should). When a file is public then you can use cloudfront easly (and it can be http since you don't need to authenticate)