# How to download files from Amazon Cloudfront via Android Amazon SDK

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Building an android app that download large files from Amazon S3 cloud. At first we got pair BUCKET_NAME + KEY from our server and downloading worked fine (using Android S3 SDK)
But now we switched to Amazon Cloudfront are getting link from our server like this:

```
https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/bigfiles/heavy.file
```

The only solution now for me is to use any another smart download manager for public links. But the issue is about saving ability of working with private links in future. And not to add another library to download files.

Do anybody solved that problem of working with cloudfront via android s3 sdk?
And did anybody know how to get bucket name if client knows only cloudfront link to file?

Searched a lot on SO, looked all available documentation on Amazon + forums with no result. Seems I am missing something but completely do not see info about it. Most people just use solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692231/migrating-s3-download-to-cloudfront-from-ios-android-app):

Comment: "Large files," you say?  How large?  CloudFront will not let you download files larger than 20GB, that's a hard limit.  If your files are that large, you will need to download from S3 directly.  If not, have you read [Serving Private Content Through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)?  It uses a different security mechanism.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, files are not larger than 20GB. And yes i have read that info about Serving Private Content. What about topic question? Have you any experience?

Comment: There is no way to learn the bucket name if all you have is the CloudFront URL.  I don't know whether it's possible to use the S3 tools to access public CloudFront files.  Private files would be less likely to work, because you'd have to configure the CloudFront distribution to forward query strings and/or `Authorization:` header, both of which would disable caching of private objects.  Using CF auth not S3, caching remains possible.

Comment: Thanks for that info @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @tv8eye - Did you achieve downloading contents from CloudFront? Can we use TransferUtility for the same?